# Php stuck because to long load on mysqli query in php function, how to fix?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

i'm using a php function to get dome mysql data from other mysql host than my webserver.

Function:

```
public function theMysqli($build){ // $build is given by othe code (no usedata)

   $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
   $catid = array( /* +/- 40 id's */ );  //data is $catid = configs::songcats();
   $type = array( /* +/- 15 captical letters */ );  //data is $type = configs::songtype();
   $limit = 20;
   $lstart = $_post['page'];
     if($lstart == ''){
        $lstart = 0;
     }
     else{
        $lstart = $lstart * $limit;
     }
   $sletter = $_POST['letter'];
   $search = $sletter.'%';
   $catquery = "SELECT songid FROM category WHERE catID IN('".implode("', '", $catid)."')";
     if ($db = $mysqli->query($catquery)){
    while($row = $db->fetch_array()){
       $idsong[] = $row; 
        }
    $db->close();
     }

   foreach($idsong as $gt){
     $songid[] = $gt['songid'];
   }
   // songid is a array over the 30000 values

   $countquery = "SELECT id FROM songlist WHERE songtype IN('".implode("', '", $type)."') AND id IN('".implode("', '", $songid)."') AND songname LIKE '".$search."'";
     if ($db = $mysqli->query($countquery)){
    $countr = $db->num_rows;
    $db->close();
     }
   $pages = ceil($countr / $limit);
   $songquery = "SELECT id, songname, artist, copyright, duration FROM songlist WHERE songtype IN('".implode("', '", $type)."') AND id IN('".implode("', '", $songid)."') AND songname LIKE '".$search."' ORDER BY songname ASC LIMIT $lstart, $limit";

   if ($db = $mysqli->query($songquery)){
      while($row2 = $db->fetch_array()){
         $result[] = $row2; 
      }
      $db->close();
   }
   if($built == 'counter'){
     $final == $pages;
   }
   else if($build == 'gresult'){
     $final == $result;
   }
   return $final;
}
```

Now my problem is the load time he need for this script it will be to long. Even when i set php.ini so that execute may be 300sec he will stuck by loading the page. Now i know you can get data grom mutiple mysql tables by one query but i can't find any solution to do that in combination with php implode function.

Total rows i must get by $_POST['letter'] M is +/- 1200; (web radio mp3 database)

Can someone help me to fix this function so i get no timeout's anymore.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're fetching a list from the database, and then sending that list back as part of a query. You should really be doing most of this stuff in SQL, using either JOIN or nested queries. This will make your program much faster.

First, create a table for all of your catids and types. Your catquery should then be:

```
SELECT songid 
FROM category 
WHERE catID IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM catids
)
```

Use the same sort of pattern to join your queries together. It looks like you can cut down most of your code here to just one SQL query. You'll save a ton of time and memory by not having to send all that data back and forth between your program and the database.

Some reading material for you:

SQL Joins: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm

SQL Subquery: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

Comment: There is a table with all the catID's but there are 100 category's and i need only 30/40 of them. Thats why array $catid is created. That are all the id's i need. This function will be used in scripts for online radio DJ's to all different users play music from differen categories. only the user database/configs are on a other mysql server. I know i can fix this with joins function only i can't find how to do it in combo with the php implode.

Comment: I find a way with joins function. arrays to string in the config and i use - query: SELECT A.id, A.artist, A.songname A.copyright FROM songlist A, category B WHERE A.artist LIKE '".$search."' AND B.catID IN (".$catid.") AND A.id = B.songid AND A.songtype IN (".$songtype."). now i can use feth_assoc() and Num_rows() on it. Problem solved. thanks.